# How to retrieve access_token from client-side OAuth 2.0 stack exchange api flow using Python?

Tags: python, stackexchange-api

I am working on my project for StackOverflow, using the API with Python. However, I need to get the [access_token] from the URL as is described in https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've answered my own question, using the redirect URL, and then I've applied it the StackExchange login procedure.